# does iframe use its own style/scripts? [Working]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Loading iframe from same domain.

**Base URL** www.example.com/dashboard

**iFrame URL** www.example.com/im

`iFrame` is called from one of the page inside `Base URL`; the `js` & `css` required by `iFrame` is being used from `Base URL` location.

If i try `iFrame` URL directly in browser; then its using its own `js` & `css` files. (i.e. www.example.com/im/js & www.example.com/im/css)

> Can i force `iFrame` to use all dependency files from its *own location*?

Code Sample:

```
#html
<iframe class="box-body" id="rmm" src="" style="display:block; width:97%; overflow: auto; position: relative;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
#script
$("#rmm").attr('src', 'www.example.com/im');
```

*Note: Using Phalcon PHP*

Comment: *does iframe use its own style/scripts?* - Yes

Comment: @awd in my case its not. if i delete `js` & `css` from `Base` location then `iFrame` also getting affected.

Comment: Make sure you use relative URLs for the dependencies, not absolute URLs. Then each will look for them in their own directory.

Comment: Finally it’s working using its own dependencies. Issue is with the code not following best practice & I overlooked....